# Reading XLS locally in asp (mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, local, xls

thanks for reading, my doubt is the following, im trying to get data from an xls file but it has to be done locally, without uploading the file, i have done something similiar with txts files and works perfectly :

```
Function Send(ByVal file As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult
    Dim line As String
    Dim textreader As System.IO.StreamReader = New StreamReader(file.InputStream)
    While Not textreader.EndOfStream
        line = textreader.ReadLine()
        ViewBag.line = line
    End While
    Return View("Index")
End Function
```

but i cant do the same to the excel file, first of all, because i cant use the streamreader, so when using this code i dont know how to specify the dir of my xls file

```
    Dim oApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    oWB = oApp.Workbooks.Open(file.inputstream)  <-- HERE IS WHERE I GET (AN OBVIOUS) ERROR
```

does anybody knows how to open the file locally? thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it, one of them is accessing the file "database style"
...

```
...
    string filePath = string.Format("C:\\TEST\\{0}.xlsx", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    var fileStream = File.Create(filePath);
    input.CopyTo(file.InputStream);
    fileStream.Close();

    string cn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath  + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
    string query = "SELECT * FROM SHEET_NAME";

    conn= new OleDbConnection(cn);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand woOleCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

    DbDataReader result = woOleCommand.ExecuteReader();

    // Read the DataReader...
...
```

So basically you query Sheets like tables, if they are indeed tables, this code might be what you're looking for.

On the other hand, if you still need to use automation, try something like this instead:

```
...    
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
wBook = (Excel._Workbook)xl.Workbooks.Open(filePath, false, false, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing); 
...
```

---

### Reading InputStream

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create(filePath)) {
     file.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream); 
} 
// Now you got your stream on a file (filePath) so you can work with it.
```

Comment: i tried something like this, but the problem is that i dont know the file path, and im not able to know it because new browsers dont show the full path

Comment: See answer updated: **Reading InputStream** copies the stream to a file. Then you can work with it. BTW, browsers won't show you the full path because of security reasons, and because it would be pointless since it's client machine path, and you won't have access to it from server side.

Comment: mm i tried something with filestream but couldnt make it, im gonna try this, tanks a lot :), sorry i cant give you rep :(

Comment: No problem, don't forget to check it as the answer if it is. Good luck.

Comment: sorry for being so noobish haha, cant make it work :(, it says "cant convert a system.io.file to system.io.stream,

Comment: i defined Dim fs As FileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path) and then FileO.InputStream.CopyTo(fs) but it doesnt work, it gives another (not the previous one)

Comment: aww, its was (obviously haha) my bad, i could make it work, thx a lot for your help :), as soon as i can im going to give you rep